# MongoDB MapReduce returning null values in PHP (but works in Javascript)

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to make a Map-Reduce command in PHP with **exactly** the same functions as in pure JavaScript and surprisingly the result is not the same. I have *null* values in PHP :-(

I have an *"employees"* collection, for each employee there is a list of *"departments"* to which he/she belongs.

So the **Javascript map-reduce code** (which works) to get the number of employees by department will be:

```
map = function() {
    if (!this.department)   {
        return;
    }
    for (i in this.department)  {
        emit(this.department[i], 1);
    };
};

reduce = function(key, values) {
    var total = 0;

    for (i in values)   {
        total += values[i];
    };

    return total;
};

retorno = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "employees",
    "map": map,
    "reduce": reduce,
    "out": "employees_by_department"
});
if (retorno.ok != 1)    {
    print(retorno.errmsg);
};

resultado = db.employees_by_department.find();
while ( resultado.hasNext() ) {
    printjson( resultado.next() );
}
```

And the equivalent **PHP code** (with *null* values) will be:

```
<?php
try {
    $connection = new MongoClient( "mongodb://localhost" ); 
    $db = $connection->selectDB("employees");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    printf("Error: %s: %s\n", "Error al conectarse a MongoDB: ",  $e->getMessage());
    die();
}


$map = new MongoCode("function() {
    if (!this.department)   {
        return;
    }
    for (i in this.department)  {
        emit(this.department[i], 1);
    };
};");

$reduce = new MongoCode("reduce = function(key, values) {
    var total = 0;

    for (i in values)   {
        total += values[i];
    };

    return total;
};");

$retorno = $db->command(array(
    "mapreduce" => "employees",
    "map" => $map,
    "reduce" => $reduce,
    "out" => "employees_by_department_php"
    ));
if ($retorno["ok"] =! 1)    {
    print($retorno["errmsg"]);
}
else {
    $resultado = $db->selectCollection("employees_by_department_php")->find();
    foreach($resultado as $dep) {
        printf("_id: \"%s\", value: %d\n", $dep["_id"], $dep["value"]);
    }
}

?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

UUpppss!! Solved! The problem was a **typo error (a copy-paste problem)** :-|

In PHP the first line of the reduce function, where it was

```
$reduce = new MongoCode("reduce = function(key, values) {
```

should be

```
$reduce = new MongoCode("function(key, values) {
```